# How merge dictionary with key values but which contains several different list values?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, merge

Someone, asked how my input looks like:
The input is an ouput from preceeding function.
And when I do

```
print(H1_dict)
```

The following information is printed to the screen:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2480: ['A', 'C', 'C'], 2651: ['T', 'A', 'G']})
```

which means the data type is **defaultdict with (keys, values)** as **(class, list)**

**So something like this:**

```
H1dict = {2480: ['A', 'C', 'C'], 2651: ['T', 'A', 'G'].....}
H2dict = {2480: ['C', 'T', 'T'], 2651: ['C', 'C', 'A'].....}

H1_p1_values = {2480: ['0.25', '0.1', '0.083'], 2651: ['0.43', '0.11', '0.23']....}
H1_p2_values = {2480: ['0.15', '0.15', '0.6'], 2651: ['0.26', '0.083', '0.23']....}

H2_p1_values = {2480: ['0.3', '0.19', '0.5'], 2651: ['0.43', '0.17', '0.083']....}

H2_p2_values = {2480: ['0.3', '0.3', '0.1'], 2651: ['0.39', '0.26', '0.21']....}
```

I want to merge this dictionaries as:

```
merged_dict (class, list) or (key, values)= {2480: h1['A', 'C', 'C'], h2 ['C', 'T', 'T'], h1_p1['0.25', '0.1', '0.083'], h1_p2['0.15', '0.15', '0.6'], h2_p1['0.3', '0.19', '0.5'], h2_p2['0.3', '0.3', '0.1'],  2651: h1['T', 'A', 'G'], h2['C', 'C', 'A']....}
```

So, I want to merge several dictionaries using key values but maintain the order in which different dictionary are supplied.

For merging the dictionary I am able to do it partially using:

```
merged = [haplotype_A, haplotype_B, hapA_freq_My, hapB_freq_My....]
merged_dict = {}
for k in haplotype_A.__iter__():
    merged_dict[k] = tuple(merged_dict[k] for merged_dict in merged)
```

But, I want to add next level of keys infront of each list, so I can access specific items in a large file when needed.

Downstream I want to access the values inside this merged dictionary using keys each time with for-loop. Something like:

```
for k, v in merged_dict:
    h1_p1sum = sum(float(x) for float in v[index] or v[h1_p1])
    h1_p1_prod = mul(float(x) for float in v[index] or v[h1_p1])
    h1_string = "-".join(str(x) for x in v[h1_index_level]
```

**and the ability to print or write it to the file line by line**
    print (h1_string)
    print (h1_p1_sum)

I am read several examples from defaultdict and other dict but not able to wrap my head around the process. I have been able to do simple operation but something like this seems a little complicated. I would really appreciate any explanation that you may add to the each step of the process.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
merged = {'h1': haplotype_A, 'h2': haplotype_B, 'h3': hapA_freq_My, ...}
merged_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for var_name in merged:
    for k in merged[var_name]:
        merged_dict[k][var_name] = merged[var_name][k]
```

This should give you an output of:

```
>>>merged_dict
{'2480': {'h1': ['A', 'C', 'C'], 'h2': ['C', 'T', 'T'], ..}, '2651': {...}}
```

given of course, the variables are the same as your example data given.

You can access them via nested `for` loops:

```
for k in merged_dict:
    for sub_key in merged_dict[k]:
        print(merged_dict[k][sub_key])  # print entire list
        for item in merged[k][sub_key]:
             print(item)  # prints item in list
```

Comment: So, how do I access each item different lists in for loop. Any idea?

Comment: you'd have to use a nested loop, I suppose - sec, I'll update my answer.

Comment: See if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: What are you refering to as `var_name` in the code.

Comment: alrite, waiting !

Comment: Why did you remove the code for sum and product. I am working on it but would like to see yours too ! Thanks much for being awesome !